# Data structure for a story with multiple endings

Tags: iphone, ios, algorithm, data-structures

I have an idea to design an story app which has multiple ending based on user's choice. 
For example :

Story 1->choices(A,B,C)->User selects A->story 2 and so on.

One way is simply create it in brute force way i.e. create the flow as it is. But then in future if I have to make changes then it will be hard. So I am thinking to create a data structure for the text but not getting any idea.

And also right now I have raw text so what format should I use to get text in my application and consume it as per the data structure?

Please guide me.

Below the pic shows the Graphic view. At root the story starts and each child is a choice. Also each child is having the story content but here in pic I have only included the choices.

[image: graphic flow of app]

I am sorry for the low resolution pic I couldn't get whole graph with big picture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imo using graphs or trees will be your best choice because of the way you can flow through such data structure much like a multiple choice story

Comment: @dbkoren thanks for reply. Can please also suggest in which format should I keep my text to use it?

Comment: Wrote you a full answer , i think it should suffice you , accept it if you find it usefull

Answer (score 1):

Best way i can think of

**1)** An Oriented Graph G(V,E) as following :

**E** =  Edges with "Weight" function that indicate the Route the user chose along the story.

**V** = Nodes that holds the part of the story you want to tell.

**Now lets do a flow simulation :**

the user reads a part of the story in the Vertices **'v1'** he is currently on, and then given multiply choices (number of edges exiting from the **'v1'**).

the user chose the path he wants to take, lets say he chose path 2.

then you advance to that Vertic\node **v2** and show the user the part of the stroy stored in the vertic\node **v2**.

**2)** For the Question on what **data type** to save the "Stroy" in ..
 that depends what more importent, HD space or a Fast loading program.

**HD space** : check out compression methods like Hoffman tree (very basic not so hard to implement \ Zip used to use this one ... maybe still i dunno )

**Fast** : i would go with a each node has a file name that can read text from a file stored on the HD. The straight forward one will be using a STRING but then you are limited to the Heap\Stack size ..

id suggest you research on how to store and load long texts and find the one suits you best.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

The best choice would be an oriented graph. Is there anything more complicated that would make this solution fail?

Answer (score 0):

I would say use a rooted tree (a tree is a graph without cycles). If you imagine your user returning to an earlier node, then you may want to use a graph instead because then you'll need cycles.